# Magento multidomain > theme messed up

Tags: magento, themes, multiple-domains

I have 3 domains sharing the same Magento installation:

mobilmonster.com, mobilmonster.it and movilmonster.es

For some strange reason domains mobilmonster.com and movilmonster.es look ok but mobilmonster.it template is all messed up. (sorry I can´t be more technical than that)

I´m not sure if it´s a missconfiguration from my behalf or there´s actually something wrong in the code, a deleted file, etc.

All suggestions welcomed!

Comment: Have set up multiple store view ??

Comment: Yes, I have http://prntscr.com/7oecdm

Comment: Check design in admin configuration with store scope

Comment: I did that. All websites, stores and views have the same settings: Use Default [STORE VIEW], Use Website [STORE VIEW]

Comment: @Pablo for mobilmonster.it website, check configuration -> web -> and the url for js and css files

Comment: @Claudiu All settings are the same for all three domains, as far as I can see. These are the settings for Mobilmonster.it:

Unsecure
Base URL = http://mobilmonster.it/
Base Link URL = {{unsecure_base_url}}
Base Skin URL = {{unsecure_base_url}}skin/Base Media URL = {{unsecure_base_url}}media/
Base JavaScript URL = {{unsecure_base_url}}js/
Secure
Same settings as Unsecure

Here you have two screenshots:

Mobilmonster.it
http://prntscr.com/7ono1f

Movilmonster.es
http://prntscr.com/7onoa8

Comment: @Pablo I suppose it is related to your settings in index.php or .htaccess. You should check those

Answer (score 0):

you are missing design to be set for the site. check attched screenshot.
[image]
After doing this delete the cache directory from var directory or FLUSH ALL MAGENTO CACHES.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you setup the addon domain incorrectly so its not inheriting the design.

Or in some cases, you have to select the store view, and resave the theme settings. Some themes generate settings based css, and has to be regenerated by resaving the settings, and flush cache.